# Group tablixes in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm making a report that is a registration form to be printed.It prints customer information in the boxes, and it also lists the available licenses that can be purchased. Right now my problem is that each customer's info is displayed first, then at the end the licenses are displayed just once. I want it to print both the customer and license tablixes on each page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use one tablix and setup parent (customer info) and child groupings. Your being a little vague. Do you have two tablixes and customer info in one with license in another?